# Showing that the smallest algebra containing a semialgebra is the class of finite unions of the semialgebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \neq \emptyset$, and $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ a semialgebra.

Apparently $$\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{C}) = \{A: A = \bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B_i, B_i \in \mathcal{C}\text{ for }i = 1, \dots, k < \infty\}\tag{1}$$ is the "smallest algebra" containing $\mathcal{C}$.

What does "smallest algebra" mean? I'm not sure. I would speculate it means something like
$$\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{C}) = \bigcap_{\mathcal{A}\in\mathcal{J}(\mathcal{C})}\mathcal{A}\tag{2}$$
where $\mathcal{J}(\mathcal{C}) = \{\mathcal{A}:\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{A}\text{ an algebra of subsets of }\Omega \}$.

From here, I'm stuck. Of course, I need to show $\subset$ and $\supset$ on $(1)$ and $(2)$, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal A\in\mathcal J(\mathcal C)$.

Then $\mathcal A(\mathcal C)\subseteq\mathcal A$ since $\mathcal A$ is closed under finite unions.

Proved is now that: $$\mathcal A(\mathcal C)\subseteq\bigcap_{\mathcal A\in\mathcal J(\mathcal C)}\mathcal A$$

Conversely if $\mathcal C$ is a semialgebra then it can be shown that $\mathcal A(\mathcal C)$ is an algebra. This evidently with $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal A(\mathcal C)$ so that $\mathcal A(\mathcal C)\in\mathcal J(\mathcal C)$.

Can you do that yourself?

This justifies the conclusion that:$$\bigcap_{\mathcal A\in\mathcal J(\mathcal C)}\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal A(\mathcal C)$$

Comment: I figured out how to show $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{C})$ is an algebra, but I'm not sure how to show $\mathcal{A}(\mathcal{C}) \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $\mathcal A\in\mathcal J(\mathcal C)$ then it is an algebra that contains $\mathcal C$. If $A\in\mathcal A(\mathcal C)$ then it is the union of sets $B_1,\dots,B_k\in\mathcal C$. Also $B_1,\dots,B_k\in\mathcal A$. Then by definition the finite union of these $B_i$ is an element of $\mathcal A$. This because algebra $\mathcal A$ is closed under finite unions.

Answer (score 0):

The smallest algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$ is indeed the intersection of all algebras containing $\mathcal{C}$.

We can characterize it by the fact that

- $\mathcal{A}({\mathcal{C}})$ is an algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$
- If $\mathcal{B}$ is an algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$, then it contains $\mathcal{A}({\mathcal{C}}$)